# When someone logged in you account in his device while you're using in your phone

Tags: google-play-store, whatsapp-messenger, hardware, chat-history

I was using my whatsapp no since many years,but today my account automatically logged out coz the same number allocated to another person as I was not using the sim (no calls &msg) I live outside my country so can he able to see my old chats &msgs
??